# Angular JS; Invalid or unexpected token, Cannot read property 'module' of undefined and angular is not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

For some reason I get these three errors when I publish my project to Azure. When I run the project on localhost these errors don't occur. I copied in the location where I declare my script files.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Sales Web App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/Style.css" type="text/css" />
    <!--<script src="../angular/angular.js"></script>-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="../angular/angular-route.js"></script>-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.17.0/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.17.0/dist/additional-methods.js"></script>
    <script src="JQuery/Script.js"></script>
    <script src="Angular/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="Sales">
    <header ng-include="'Header.html'"></header>

    <br />
    <main ng-view></main>

</body>
```

From what I've read up my scripts all appear to be in the correct order.

Comment: Using the network tab in the Chrome developer tools, are any of the js files not getting loaded?

Comment: I'm not sure yet, I've deleted the Azure Web app and starting again. If the error occurs again, I should know within 30 mins.

Comment: Ok, re-uploaded everything, and haven't had the errors yet, everything seems to be working.

Comment: Modern day equivalent of rebooting. ;)